# How to call camera intent in CustomAdapter class in android?

Tags: java, android

I have Adapter class called CustomListAdapter class i written like this,so here i get a problem class cast exception Any one suggest me

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myplace, null);

    final ImageView ivCamera = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);

    ivCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
            adb.setTitle("Do u Want to Take Photo");
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    count++;
                    String file = dir+count+".jpg";
                    File newfile = new File(file);
                    try {
                        newfile.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

                    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

                }
            });

            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            adb.show();
        }
    });
}
```

I get class cast exception please suggest me how to resolve this issue

in My Activity i call This method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    customListAdapter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ivCamera.setImageBitmap(bp);
}
```

Comment: please post you log cat trace.

Comment: create camera intent method on activity and call this method on alert dialog ok

Comment: same error its showing

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3505)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3466)
            at info.androidhive.Labelleza.Activities.NearByActivity.CameraCapture(NearByActivity.java:204)
            at info.androidhive.Labelleza.adapter.CustomListAdapter$3$1.onClick(CustomListAdapter.java:152)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)

Comment: Your context may be null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    customListAdapter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ivCamera.setImageBitmap(bp);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting the error in CustomList Adapter class                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
            at info.androidhive.Labelleza.adapter.CustomListAdapter$3$1.onClick(CustomListAdapter.java:167)

Comment: Yes. Now what is on line 167?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

1) you have no check - probably onActivityResult() fires after some other activities started for result

2) resultCode == RESULT_OK && extras != null && extras.get("data") != null could be critical

3) try to run the receiving code in debug mode - some devices may not pass the bitmap (because it's very big, for example). if so - try to supply photoURI and then resize the photo before showing it

4) try to find libraries for getting photo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are 2 types of Context in Android. 1 of them is Activity-type, the other - application Context.
Obviously, you should pass to adapter ref to your Activity, i.e. new Adapter(YourActivity.this), rather than new Adapter(getApplicationContext())

Answer the question - what activity should perform onActivityResult(), if you start activity for result using just getApplicationContext().startActivityForResult()? - And all become obvious.